# getting error while using using JdbcChannelMessageStore in spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

This is how I implemented the JdbcChannelMessageStore in my application:

```
<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
        <int:after-commit expression="@store.removeFromIdCache(headers.id)" />
        <int:after-rollback expression="@store.removeFromIdCache(headers.id)"/>
    </int:transaction-synchronization-factory>
     
     <task:executor id="pool" pool-size="10"  queue-capacity="10" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />

        <int:channel id="objectToJsonChannelTMF639">
        <int:queue message-store="store"/>
        <!--<int:interceptors>
            <bean class="ca.bell.bmf.customer.service.MyChannelInterceptor" />
        </int:interceptors>-->
    </int:channel>       
  
    <bean id="store" class="org.springframework.integration.jdbc.store.JdbcChannelMessageStore">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="channelMessageStoreQueryProvider" ref="queryProvider"/>
        <property name="region" value="CONCURRENT_POLL"/>
        <property name="usingIdCache" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    
    <int:bridge input-channel="objectToJsonChannelTMF639">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="500" receive-timeout="500"
            max-messages-per-poll="1" task-executor="pool">
            <int:transactional propagation="REQUIRED" synchronization-factory="syncFactory"
            isolation="READ_COMMITTED" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
        </int:poller>
    </int:bridge>
```

I am having trouble with inserting data into the database using JdbcChannelMessageStore. I get the following error when I run my code:

[2023-08-10 00:08:38,909] ERROR org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler:250 - ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.jdbcMessageStoreChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=CPMPayload [cpmBody=[{"op":"replace","jsonPath":"$.resourceCharacteristic[?(@.name=='AStatus')].value","value":"returned"},{"op":"replace","jsonPath":"$.resourceCharacteristic[?(@.name=='FStatus')].value","value":"FCredited"},{"op":"replace","jsonPath":"$.resourceCharacteristic[?(@.name=='tmpCPMData_orderId')].value","value":"89CJ00"}], domain=logicalResource, transactionID=44234, externalid=89CJ00, specName=VideoCpe_LD, externalId=COM-BC743HE1C-1-1, sourceSystem=3PL-Process, transnSeqId=44234], headers={id=bb7a6bac-7767-5467-490a-c326e780e0ab, timestamp=1691606317062}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=CPMPayload [cpmBody=[{"op":"replace","jsonPath":"$.resourceCharacteristic[?(@.name=='AStatus')].value","value":"returned"},{"op":"replace","jsonPath":"$.resourceCharacteristic[?(@.name=='FStatus')].value","value":"FCredited"},{"op":"replace","jsonPath":"$.resourceCharacteristic[?(@.name=='tmpCPMData_orderId')].value","value":"89CJ00"}], domain=logicalResource, transactionID=44234, externalid=89CJ00, specName=VideoCpe_LD, externalId=COM-BC743HE1C-1-1, sourceSystem=3PL-Process, transnSeqId=44234], headers={id=bb7a6bac-7767-5467-490a-c326e780e0ab, timestamp=1691606317062}], headers={id=5458abcc-d97f-5b0f-9278-5525d2663fa8, timestamp=1691606318909}] for original GenericMessage [payload=CPMPayload [cpmBody=[{"op":"replace","jsonPath":"$.resourceCharacteristic[?(@.name=='AStatus')].value","value":"returned"},{"op":"replace","jsonPath":"$.resourceCharacteristic[?(@.name=='FStatus')].value","value":"FCredited"},{"op":"replace","jsonPath":"$.resourceCharacteristic[?(@.name=='tmpCPMData_orderId')].value","value":"89CJ00"}], domain=logicalResource, transactionID=44234, externalid=89CJ00, specName=VideoCpe_LD, externalId=COM-BC743HE1C-1-1, sourceSystem=3PL-Process, transnSeqId=44234], headers={id=bb7a6bac-7767-5467-490a-c326e780e0ab, timestamp=1691606317062}]

I am facing with the database. I have observed that the data I am inserting into the DB is disappearing after refreshing. The commit operation is also not happening, Please let me know what could be the cause of this problem and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error says this:

```
Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.jdbcMessageStoreChannel'.
```

So, there is a `jdbcMessageStoreChannel` in your application where you try to send a message. You don't show that config in your question, but be sure that you have a subscriber for that channel to make it working.

The config you show so far has nothing to do with that error.